# Unsetting a variable but it wouldn't unset

Tags: javascript

Below is the code snippet. I am trying to create 16 x 16 grid divs and after every 15 I am trying to add a new line to it. To do the following I am adding the line class with the value 'change' on  every 16th element. But it wouldn't work and all my first 240 elements will have the value 'change' for the 'line' class and the last 16 elements will have the value ''. As intended the console.log for the line displays the right behaviour (i.e. after every 15 nulls there is a change displayed)

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    createDivs(16);
});

var createDivs = function (grids) {
    for (var i = 0; i < grids; i++) {
        var j = 0;
        var line = '';
        for (; j < grids; j++) {
            var grid = '<div id=' + i + '' + j + '></div>';
            if (j === 0) {
                line = 'change';
            }
            console.log(line);
            $('#container').append(grid);
            $('#container > div').addClass('grid-class');
            $('#container > div').addClass(line);
            line = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
$('#container > div').addClass(line);
```

will add that class to *every single div* matching the selector. When `line` is `null`, nothing new is added, but neither is anything deleted.

A cleaned-up variant, also no longer repeatedly adding `grid-class` to every single `div`, would be:

```
var ctr = $('#container');

for (var i = 0; i < grids; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < grids; j++) {
    var grid = $('<div id=' + i + '' + j + '></div>')
      .addClass('grid-class');

    if (j == 0)
      grid.addClass('change');

    ctr.append(grid);
  }
}
```

Comment: `grid` is a DOM string, not a jQuery collection.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#container').append(grid);
$('#container > div').addClass('grid-class');
$('#container > div').addClass(line);
```

You're selecting all of the divs, not just the most recent one. You could solve that simply by adding a `:last` selector:

```
$('#container').append(grid);
$('#container > div:last').addClass('grid-class');
$('#container > div:last').addClass(line);
```

You could also simplify this by doing it all on a jQuery object created out of `grid`:

```
$(grid).addClass('grid-class').addClass(line).appendTo('#container');
```